# Install and use react 0.14.0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, browserify

I am trying to use react- 0.14.0 in my project , and I am getting this error

> Invariant Violation: ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React.

this is the code :

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')

var Scanner = require('./scanner')
var dictionary = {
    list-users : [
        {
        name : "Alex",
        age : "24",
        profile : "../images/profile.jpg"

        },
       {
        name : "David",
        age : "22",
        profile : "../images/profile2.jpg"

        }
    ]
}

var elemnet = React.createElement(Scanner,dictionary)
ReactDOM.render(elemnet,document.querySelector('.content'))
```

the  node_modules shows:
react 0.13.3
and react-dom 0.14.0

Comment: Try upgrading react 0.13.0 to 0.14.0

Comment: I installed react agin using  `npm install --save react react-dom` but react version stays 0.13.3

Comment: `npm uninstall react; npm install --save react`. the ole unplug it, plug it back in move.

Comment: same result react 0.13.3 :/

Comment: I installed the same way you did...check the react folder inside react-dom you might get the latest version

Comment: react-dom shows the latest version but react shows the previous one . the error says `This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React` its somehow strange for me

Comment: Try running `npm cache clean` before reinstalling

Comment: check you have node_modules folder in react-dom folder..if so check inside node_modules you have new react v14.0 `react-dom@0.14.0 node_modules\react-dom
└── react@0.14.0 (envify@3.4.0, fbjs@0.3.1)` .Because of that only you are getting `This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React`

Comment: done , that's helpfull , thanks @PraveenRaj

Comment: Why is npm so bad when all they had to do was rip off bundler

Comment: try 
```npm unlink react
  rm -rf node_modules/react
  npm i react@latest```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you have node_modules folder in react-dom folder..if so check inside 
node_modules you have new react v14.0.

```
react-dom@0.14.0 node_modules\react-dom 
        └── react@0.14.0 (envify@3.4.0, fbjs@0.3.1)
```

You have React folder of v13.0 in node_Modules and V14.0 inside react_dom.Because of that two react folder you are getting

```
This may be caused by unintentionally loading two independent copies of React
```